# DAX grand total "wrong" for price variance

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have repeatedly ran into the following problem when calculating variances, that the grand totals are calculated wrong. Although they are not technically wrong, I want to calculate them differently. The picture below shows what I have constructed in PowerPivot.

[image: data]

Formulas:

```
ACT Sales EUR = CALCULATE([Sales EUR];FILTER(data;data[Type] = "ACT"))
ACT Sales/kg = DIVIDE([ACT Sales EUR];[ACT Sales KG])
FC Sales/kg = DIVIDE([FC Sales EUR];[FC Sales KG]
Quantity Variance = ([ACT Sales KG] - [FC Sales KG]) * [FC Sales/kg]
Price Variance = ([ACT Sales/kg] - [FC Sales/kg]) x [ACT Sales KG]
```

The total variance is equal to column [Sales ACT vs FC EUR], but I would like the grand total for the variances to be a simple sum of the rows, and not using the measure formula on the grand total. How should this be done correctly?

The column structure for the data is as follows (where Type is either ACT, BUD, FC):

```
| Date | Type | Product | EUR | KG |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix variance totals, you need to iterate over product and then sum up the results:

```
Quantity Variance = (
SUMX(
   VALUES( Data[Product]),
   [ACT Sales KG] - [FC Sales KG]) * [FC Sales/kg]
)
```

(same for the other variance)

Comment: Simple and correct, thank you! Now if only I understood what the values function does. But this example should help me understand it.

Comment: VALUES function selects a list of products visible in a current filter context. In a row, it's just 1 product in that row; in the totals, it's all products. Then SUMX iterates this list record by record and computes proper variances and then sums the results up.

Comment: RADO, can you still help me with this? What if e.g. [ACT Sales KG] is blank. This causes both variances to be blank. I tried inserting `IF( ISBLANK( [ACT Sales KG] ) ; -[FC Sales KG] ;yourPreviousFormula )` inside the SUMX, but this does not change anything. If it is inserted outside, then the grand totals are again wrong. Sorry, but there is something fundamental that I'm not getting in this structure.